# Register Uses in RISC-V

Tags: riscv

Am I loading the wrong register here!!!

RISC-V Error Message is:

```
Error in line 8: "t1" operand is of incorrect type
```

The Code is:

```
         .data
 var_a:   .byte 23 52 63 72
  var_b:   .word 235 263 722 352
          .text
  main:  lui  s0, 0x10010
         lw   t0, 4(s0)
         lb   t1, 2(s0)
         addi t2, t0, t1
        lb   t3, 3(s0)
         sub t4, t2, t3
         sw   t4, 22(s0)
 exit:   ori  a7, zero, 10
            ecall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addi` is used for adding a register and an immediate (thus the "i" at the end), a constant value; such as `addi t2, t0, 5` (`t2 = t0 + 5`). Use `add` instead; `add t2, t0, t1`